# how can i convert a variable from string into html same l and pass it as a value for components props variables accepts string

Tags: vue.js, variables, nuxt.js, formkit

i am using a module (formKit) components accepts props to pass your text you want to write in, and my problem is how can i pass an HTML variable as string to props values same like:

from template
this point >> :label="'Your name' + parseHTML(tooltip)"

```
<FormKit type="text" name="name" :label="'Your name' + parseHTML(tooltip)" help="What do people call you?" validation="required" :classes="inputTextStyle" />'
```

from script

```
const tooltip = ref("<div class='tooltip'>(?)</div>")
```

how can i make this variable parsing as HTML Element and the props value accept it with no problem

Comment: You can't force a prop to parse an HTML string if it's not designed to do it. According to the FormKit API, `label` accepts a standard string and that's all.  What you _can_ do according to the API is provide a [label slot](https://formkit.com/essentials/inputs#slots) that replaces all of the HTML of the FormKit's label section. If you're not familiar with slots in Vue, you should first read the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) on slots.

Comment: ohhh, sure many thanks for you, am already familiar with slots and i will try this if can with formKit, but i think this is more complex but no problem trying things thank you pro.